# Properties of $x^{n}\sin\frac{1}{x}$ at 0

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Consider the function

$$\begin{cases}x^{n}\sin\frac{1}{x}, & x\neq0\\0, & x=0\end{cases};\; n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Question 1. Does it have a name? I've met it in several textbooks on analysis, but none provides its name.

Question 2 (every property below is considered at 0). Learning that

$\sin\frac{1}{x}$ is discontinuous,

$x\sin\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous, i.e. $\in C^{0}$

$x^{2}\sin\frac{1}{x}$ is differentiable

$x^{3}\sin\frac{1}{x}$ is continuously differentiable, i.e. $\in C^{1}$

I have a hunch that this pattern (i.e. adding new “layer” of continuity, then differentiability) goes on as n is increased. To be more specific, consider the claim:

$$\begin{cases}x^{n}\sin\frac{1}{x}, & x\neq0\\0, & x=0\end{cases}\in C^{\frac{n-1}{2}};\; n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Is it true? (let me remind you that we're discussing all that only at 0.)

Comment: Not $(n-1)/2$ because at zero $f(x)=O(x^n)$ so it is more $n-1$ or $n-2$. Don't you think?

Comment: In Italy this function is often referred to as *Topologist's sine*.

Comment: I agreed with @marwalix, it should be $n-1$.

Comment: @CheeHan, that implies that $x^2 sin (1/x)$ is $C^1$, but it is not.

Comment: You just said $x^2\sin(1/x)$ is differentiable and $x\sin(1/x)$ is continuous?

Comment: @CheeHan, the derivative of $x^2 \sin (1/x) = 2x \sin (1/x) - cos(1/x)$ which isn't continuous at 0.

Comment: AHHHHHHHHH my bad, I forgot about that............